# Reading unclosed tag xml and editing during reading

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Hi I have a scenario here. I have one XML and it has some unclosed tags. When i try to load the xml it gives me exception saying some of the tags are unclosed.

Is there any better way to read xml with unclosed tags and update same time if i encounter unclosed tags with manually closing tags.

Currently i am reading all the xml content and putting into list and again reading entire list and if i encounter unclosed tags i am just adding something like "". it works fine. but takes lot of time. Is there any better way of doing this?

Please suggest. My XML structure is as follows

```
<Root>
<LogEntries>
<LogEntry>
</LogEntry>
   ...
</LogEntries>
<LogEntry>
  ....
</LogEntry>
</Root>
```

I am missing logentries closing tag here.

Comment: You should always fix the program that generated bad xml structure, not attempt to patch the file.

Comment: I agree. But log structure will break during ungraceful application exit. say for example, during debug mode if i stop the debug logs wont be closed properly. I am particularly facing this scenario.

Comment: If you want to do this then write code for validating `xml tags` and if you face any problems while writing, post it here.

Comment: Are you useing xmlDocument or XmlWriter?